# Cannot edit files when opened via msoFileDialogOpen in VBA for Excel 2016

Tags: vba, excel

What I'm trying to do is open a file with the .csv extension, search for a string and then replace it with another string. I did this via msoFileDialogOpen and Selection.Replace. Windows Explorer opens and I can search, but the data in the .csv files doesn't display in Excel, no matter what I do. Funny thing is, I have another macro with the exact same msoFileDialogOpen code and there it works. Also tried to copy/paste this code and adjust it, but nothing.

I really have no idea what this is and how to fix it. I tried different codes, but unfortunately they don't work. Here is my code:

```
     Private Sub Comma()
    ' Opens the Windows File Explorer, so you can select csv files
        Dim dlgResult
        Dim ofd As FileDialog
        Set ofd = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogOpen)
            With ofd
              .AllowMultiSelect = False
              .Filters.Clear
              .Filters.Add "CSV files", "*.csv", 1
              .Show
        If .SelectedItems.Count <> 0 Then
            dlgResult = .SelectedItems.Item(1)
        Else
            MsgBox "You selected Cancel. Macro will now exit"
        Exit Sub
    End If
    End With
' This removes the annoying unnecessary double qoute within the logfiles, so you can actually run the csv macro without screwing everything up
    dlgResult = "TEXT;" & dlgResult
        With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:= _
            dlgResult, _
            Destination:=Range("$A$1:$P$9999"))
            Range("A1:P5000").Select
            Selection.Replace What:="""", Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlPart, _
                SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False
            ThisWorkbook.RefreshAll

            Selection.Replace What:=",,", Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlPart, _
                SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False
            ThisWorkbook.RefreshAll

            Selection.Replace What:=",,", Replacement:=",", LookAt:=xlPart, _
                SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False
            ThisWorkbook.RefreshAll


    ' This will overwrite the logfile.
        ThisWorkbook.SaveCopyAs _
        Filename:="C:\Dir\Dir\Dir\Dir\Dir" & "\" & _
        ThisWorkbook.Name
            MsgBox "File saved in the Logs directory."

    ' This will clear the sheet and opens the menu again, so you can continu with the next macro
    '   Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    '   Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:P5000").Clear
    '   Application.DisplayAlerts = True
        MacroSelect.Show
    End With
    End Sub
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: have you stepped through the code first ?

Comment: Yes, but I didn't found anything that might cause it and the program doesn't give me any kind of error.

Comment: I fixed the issue by adding some format and page layout code, but now if I run the other macro, not the macro which I discussed above, I get incredible gibberish. Here is an example:
ùR<2zú]«ö˜û"š q xù$½éŒÌ½ùl {y FëÙtu çñˆ{üÆç.ðÃððÜµa¼´LPÎä¡W‡/worksheets/_rels/sheet1.xml.rels .

The document is filled with this. What is this and how do I get rid of this? The expected outcome should have been several charts. Is it because  I ran a macro on the original logfile, backed it up and then I ran it  again with an different macro?

Comment: I also fixed the issue above.

Comment: well done! what did you do?

Comment: A bit late, but I will post the answer shortly.